# Postgres database encoding problem

Tags: postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I'm striving to convert badly encoded data from my table. For instance, I have a field with `NadÃ¨ge` which should be `Nadège`.

I tried using Postgres's functions `convert`, `convert_from`, `convert_to` without much success.

```
db=# SHOW client_encoding;
 client_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)

db=# SHOW server_encoding;
 server_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)

db=# SELECT "firstName", encode("firstName"::bytea, 'hex') FROM contact;       
 firstName |       encode       
-----------+--------------------
 Nadège    | 4e6164c3a86765
 NadÃ¨ge   | 4e6164c383c2a86765
(2 rows)

db=# SELECT "firstName", convert_from("firstName"::bytea, 'latin1') FROM contact WHERE "lastName" ILIKE 'crochard';
 firstName |  convert_from  
-----------+----------------
 Nadège    | NadÃ¨ge
 NadÃ¨ge   | NadÃ\u0083Â¨ge
(2 rows)

db=# SELECT "firstName", convert("firstName"::bytea, 'utf8', 'latin1') FROM contact;                                                                                                                                                       
 firstName |     convert      
-----------+------------------
 Nadège    | \x4e6164e86765
 NadÃ¨ge   | \x4e6164c3a86765
(2 rows)
```

Using python I'm able to get the correct encoding with:

```
data.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

**Any hint on how to convert these wrongly encoded data in postgres ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have correctly identified, `NadÃ¨ge` is the UTF-8 representation of    `Nadège` incorrectly decoded as ISO-8859-1 ("latin-1"). Then, in your case, re-encoded to UTF-8 for storage in the DB.

To fix it you need to:

- Take the current representation and decode the UTF-8 to latin-1 as a byte string
- re-interpret the byte string, decoding it as utf-8

So:

```
test=> SELECT convert_from(convert_to('NadÃ¨ge', 'latin-1'), 'utf-8');
 convert_from 
--------------
 Nadège
(1 row)
```

---

The Python equivalent would be close to what you wrote, but starts with a unicode representation to illustrate that PostgreSQL stores everything in the database encoding. Something like:

```
>>> print u"NadÃ¨ge".encode("latin-1").decode("utf-8")
Nadège
```

---

The problem with all your attempted solutions is that the cast from `text` to `bytea` *uses the database encoding*. So you're starting with the bytes for the utf-8 representation of utf-8 mis-decoded as latin-1. With the cast you'd have to write:

```
test=> SELECT convert_from(convert_to(convert_from((TEXT 'NadÃ¨ge')::bytea, 'utf-8'), 'latin-1'), 'utf-8');
 convert_from 
--------------
 Nadège
(1 row)
```

because you have to explicitly decode the utf-8 representation produced by the cast before re-interpreting as latin-1 and decoding again.

You just needed to use `convert_to(mycol, 'latin-1')` instead of `mycol::bytea`

Comment: We have solved our encoding issue with perl yesterday, so I cannot try out in a real environment. But your explanation about `bytea` casting and why we failed to convert seems to be the exact point. I accept your answer, thank you :)

Comment: The second solution with the `::bytea` cast, has one unexpected caveat: Backslashes in the text string need to be escaped (i.e. doubled), since `bytea`'s input function interprets them as special!